# What is the reason for other coins appearing like FTC and LTC?

Tags: litecoin

Is it simply just trying to be faster and better in some aspects than bitcoins?

Comment: What do you mean "appearing like" them? You mean the graphical appearance of their clients? The structure of their addresses? Something else???

Comment: Must things have reasons? Someone felt like making them and now the exist.